# How to start an activity from a custom ListView?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a custom listview in which I can add as many elements as I want. All of these elements must open an activity (which is called "Compile" in my project) with a few edittext stuff to fill. The problem is that I don't actually know what to write in my code to tell the app to open the Compile activity when one of the elements is clicked.

//(Obviously every element must open its Compile activity with its relative informations. For example: element "Pizza" must open the activity Compile in which there are all the infos I previously put about Pizza.)//

Thanks for the support

This is my code for the listview:

```
public class Sheet extends Activity {

    private static final int DIALOG_ALERT = 10;

    ListView list;
    ImageView addBtn;
    EditText input;

    String[] items;
    MyListAdapter adapter;
    AlertDialog alert;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sheet);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        addBtn = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.addPlanBtn);

        input = new EditText(this);

        items = new String[1];

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Sheet.this).create();
        alert.setTitle("Activity name: ");
        alert.setMessage("Type a name for your activity: ");
        alert.setView(input);


        alert.setButton("add", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String value = input.getText().toString();

                items[items.length - 1] = value;

                adapter = new MyListAdapter(Sheet.this, items);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                String[] temp = new String[items.length +1];

                for(int i = 0; i< items.length; i++)
                    temp[i] = items[i];

                items = temp;

                alert.dismiss();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });

        addBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                alert.show();
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
        Object selectedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
        //Do something with your object. If it's a String and you want to send it to CompileActivity, do it like this:
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompileActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("some-data-id", (String)selectedItem)
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

In CompileActivity, you can use the sent data like so:

```
String selectItem = getIntent().getStringExtra("some-data-id");
```

Please keep in mind that Intents send copies of your data across activities. Changing this string does not change the one from the previous activity. It is just a copy.

Intents are basic building blocks for Android, so it is worth learning more about them. Here is a [place to start](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your listView's OnItemClickListener:

```
Intent newActivity = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompileActivity.class); 
//You could pass extra info here using  newActivity.putExtra(). 
// Like   newActivity.putExtra("Pizza", "Pizza name");
startActivity(newActivity);
```

Comment: Doesn't work, actually it starts CompileActivity but then when i go back to my listview I can't get back to the element's relative CompileActivity

Comment: What do you mean by `can't get back to the element's relative CompileActivity`? What happens? an error?

Comment: I mean that I can go to the compile activity only once, I can't go back there not even by clicking the item i created on the listview

Answer (score 0):

In your list view activity class set "setOnItemClickListener" for your listview. And from there start a new activity.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(),yourActivity.class);
    //you can add some extras if you want like this
    intent.putExtra("Key",Value);
    startActivity(intent);

                }

            });
```

You can retrieve the value in called activity like this :

```
int variable = getIntent().getIntExtra("Key", someDefaultIntValue);
```

Please note you can replace int here with your datatype.